# Sound Output keeps reselecting built-in Output, from Bluetooth Device

Tags: mac, bluetooth, system-settings

I have a Logitech Blue Tooth audio adapter which has been working for like 2 years.  All of a sudden, in sys preferences, it automatically switches to built-in sound.

The bluetooth, is connected in bluetooth settings, and the sound device appears in the sound settings.  But when I select it, it selects for 1 second, then goes back to built-in sound.

I've restarted, shut-down and wait, reset smc, pram, reset bluetooth, reset device and none of that affects this.

Is this a bluetooth problem, a logitech problem, or a mac problem?  I can't get any help from Logitech because I have no credit with them and their support and website is trash.